# Is the cuspidal cubic $V(x^2-y^3)$ isomorphic to $A^1$? If not, is it bijective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the cuspidal cubic $V(x^2-y^3)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_k$? If not, is it bijective?

It seems that $V(x^2-y^3)$ consists of points $(t^3,t^2)\in \mathbb{A}^2_k$. If it is, then the bijection is obvious. But I can not even prove this. Here the base field $k$ is algebraically closed. Thanks!

Comment: In what sense is that a hyperbola?

Comment: It's not a hyperbola. It is a cubic curve with a cusp. It is isomorphic to $A^1$ in the sense that their function fields are isomorphic (that parametrization using $t$ is crucial here). It is not isomorphic to $A^1$ in the sense that their coordinate rings are not isomorphic (the coordinate ring of this curve is not integrally closed in its field of fractions - due to the cusp).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right and sorry about that! Your comments helps a lot. But how can I see there are only points of the form $(t^3,t^2)$ in the algebraic set?

Comment: Hint: Show that, at points other than the cusp $(x,y)=(0,0)$ setting $t=x/y$ implies (together with the equation of the curve) that $x=t^3, y=t^2$.